# How do I set android:layout_weight on a text view programmatically?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a table layout in XML that does exactly what I want:

```
<TableRow  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/evenrow">
<TextView android:text="Check" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:layout_weight="1"></TextView>
```

I am trying to add the table row programmatically, but I can't seem to get the layout_weight set. Here is the java code:

```
TableRow.LayoutParams trlayout = new TableRow.LayoutParams (TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
TableLayout.LayoutParams tablelayout = new TableLayout.LayoutParams (TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.setLayoutParams(trlayout);
    TextView check = new TextView(this);
    check.setText(String.format("%5.2f", i)); 
    tr.addView(check);
```

I thought the 3rd param to new TableRow.LayoutParams was the default weight for the row's children, but it is not working.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

Well in a regular XML if you set `wrap_content` on the dimension of orientation you want to expand in then layout weight has no effect.

Change the width parameter to "0dp" and then your layout weight should work.